# Saving e-mail address to SIM card memory in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, gsm, cdma, sim-card

Does anyone know whether a SIM card can accomodate an e-mail field in its memory? I want to do it through an android application.

Users can save contact name and number to a SIM card, but how about an e-mail field also along with name and number; does the SIM card has memory/provision for accomodating an e-mail field also, so that it could be added through android app?

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

regards,
Anees

Answer (score 0):

sim card has little storage capacity. But it can save email address. If your one contact has one phone number, email address. Then it saved in Sim card as two contacts. Phone number and email save separately.